# Disable WIN+D key in IE browser

Tags: php, javascript, internet-explorer

I am working on javascript and php, I want to disable the win+d key functionality and minimize button from browser(IE). I am using full-screen mode in java-script.Please help me.

Comment: do you have any specific version(s) of IE in mind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't disable an operating system functionality from your scripts. Software running on Windows can disable it, though, through low level keyboard hooks. But there isn't any way to do so, and never will be, from a website.

You want some sort of "kiosk" software to run your webpage in. Those are meant for this purpose, to allow users to view a website but not mess with the rest of the system.

Comment: I have blocked win key and many other keys but i can not able to restrain minimize function of browser.

Comment: @ParthSarthiGour again, you want a "kiosk" browser. Run the browser in full screen, where the minimize button doesn't show.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this is possible without doing it at the kernel level.  The Windows Key is intended to be used by the OS and not individual applications.

Answer (score 1):

The Win+D shortcut is provided by Windows.  There is nothing that IE can do to disable this behavior.

It's unlikely that you will be able to disable the minimize button.

In essence, it sounds like what you are trying to do is prevent the user from leaving the browser window.  If browsers let this happen, that would be a tremendous security risk.  A good browser will actually try to prevent you from accomplishing this goal.